# Android Fragment InterstitialAd onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, admob

I am using a navigation drawer with fragments and inside one of the fragments I have a multi level list. 
In my `ActionBarActivity.java` I have:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       ...
        // returning to previous
        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and the `onBackPressed();` :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        // return to the previous fragment stack
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            // show the ad
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

I want to display `InterstitialAd` when the user clicks back button in the multi level list fragment. The above solution works, but it only shows the ad once on a single item.

So here is a sample run:

```
- user opens the app and first fragments lists a list of items
- user clicks on Item #1 and enters that item details
- user clicks back (Ad is shown) and goes back to all items
- user clicks on Item #2 and enters that item details
- user clicks back (but Ad is not shown) and goes back to all items
```

not sure why when the user clicks the back for the second time and so on, ad is not shown. Can someone suggest a possible solution?

**update #1:** 
here is how I create the interstitial ads on `onCreate`:

```
    // interstitial ads
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_ID);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdClosed() {
       }
   });
   requestNewInterstitial();
```

and :

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After showing an interstitial you need to call `interstital.loadAd()` again.

So call it from `onAdClosed()` (as well as in `onCreate()`).

Comment: I updated the question, can you please take a look at again?